# jQuery - does the submit event hold the query string or data of the submitted form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
$("#dummy_div").on('submit', "form", function(event){
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Does the event object contain hold the query string or data of the submitted form? If not, is there a way to get them short of iterating over the form fields?

Comment: Do you want all form values in jvascript vars? you could use jQuery each to iterate over the fields. or use the  .serializeArray().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the query string for a form is quite easy, just use [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) may be also helpful

Answer (score 3):

no the event doesn't store the querystring, but you could obtain all the fields value via `serialize()` jQuery method applied to the form to obtain a querystring-like value

See http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ for further reference

Answer (score 2):

You can use [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

```
$("#dummy_div").on('submit', "form", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
       url: form.attr('action'),
       type: form.attr('method'),
       data: form.serialize(),
       success: function(r) { }
    });
});
```